# Logon screen resolution on two displays (Intel HD Graphics)

Tags: 13.04, graphics, resolution, intel-graphics, login-screen

I have a laptop with Intel HD Graphics and resolution 1366 x 768 (d.1) and a display with resolution 1280 x 1024 (d.2). 
When I connected it via VGA while in my desktop it worked all right, but after reboot there was a problem with a resolution. In logon-screen my laptop-display (d.1) had a resolution of the second display (d.2). 
I logged on and saw that while loading there was a half of the picture was on d.1  and a half on d.2, then it was all right again, but after reboot i had on both displays a resolution of d.1. 
So it switches without any action by me. 
How can I do something with it?
I have Ubuntu 13.04
(Sorry for grammar, I'm just learning English)

Comment: I have this problem also with a 17" LG screen by VGA and the HP Pavilion dv6 15" screen.